# Swift package: error: product dependency 'LineNoise' in package 'linenoise-swift' not found

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I am using Swift package manager to manage dependencies in my project. I am trying to import LineNoise in my swift package, but I get this:

```
nathanfallet:SwiftMC nathanfallet$ swift run
Fetching https://github.com/andybest/linenoise-swift.git
Fetching https://github.com/Quick/Nimble.git
Fetching https://github.com/apple/swift-argument-parser
Fetching https://github.com/apple/swift-nio.git
Fetching https://github.com/adam-fowler/compress-nio.git
Cloning https://github.com/apple/swift-nio.git
Resolving https://github.com/apple/swift-nio.git at 2.17.0
Cloning https://github.com/adam-fowler/compress-nio.git
Resolving https://github.com/adam-fowler/compress-nio.git at 0.3.0
Cloning https://github.com/apple/swift-argument-parser
Resolving https://github.com/apple/swift-argument-parser at 0.0.6
Cloning https://github.com/andybest/linenoise-swift.git
Resolving https://github.com/andybest/linenoise-swift.git at 0.0.3
Cloning https://github.com/Quick/Nimble.git
Resolving https://github.com/Quick/Nimble.git at 7.3.4
'SwiftMC' /Users/nathanfallet/git/SwiftMC: error: product dependency 'LineNoise' in package 'linenoise-swift' not found
```

It is not the first package I import, and others are working (and I'm importing them the same way). I added the package to my `Package.swift` file like my other packages, but this one seems to be not working...

My `Package.swift` file:

```swift
// swift-tools-version:5.2
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "SwiftMC",
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries produced by a package, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "SwiftMC",
            targets: ["SwiftMC"]),
        .executable(
            name: "SwiftMCRun",
            targets: ["SwiftMCRun"])
    ],
    dependencies: [
        // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
        .package(url: "https://github.com/apple/swift-nio.git", from: "2.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/adam-fowler/compress-nio.git", from: "0.0.1"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/apple/swift-argument-parser", from: "0.0.1"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/andybest/linenoise-swift.git", from: "0.0.1")
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages which this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "SwiftMC",
            dependencies: [
                .product(name: "NIO", package: "swift-nio"),
                .product(name: "CompressNIO", package: "compress-nio")
            ]),
        .target(
            name: "SwiftMCRun",
            dependencies: [
                "SwiftMC",
                .product(name: "ArgumentParser", package: "swift-argument-parser"),
                .product(name: "LineNoise", package: "linenoise-swift") // Error seems to come from here; I tried "linenoise", "LineNoise", "linenoise-swift" but nothing seems to work
            ]),
        .testTarget(
            name: "SwiftMCTests",
            dependencies: ["SwiftMC"]),
    ]
)
```

Any idea of what is wrong with it? Why is this package not importing while others are?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Cause:

This issue happens when packages specify a different `Package.name` property compared to the github repo name. E.g. LineNoise's repo name is `linenoise-swift` but the [`Package.swift` says is called `LineNoise`](https://github.com/andybest/linenoise-swift/blob/cbf0a35c6e159e4fe6a03f76c8a17ef08e907b0e/Package.swift#L8). You'll notice all your other dependencies have github repo name consistent with package.swift package name.

### Fix: Just the package name to `.package`

To fix this, specify the **package name** of the package dependency explicitly in your `Package.swift` (you can find the name in the libraries package.swift file).

```swift
// Latest prerelease
.package(name: "LineNoise", url: "https://github.com/andybest/linenoise-swift", from: "0.0.3")
```

Now in your target dependency, you can use `LineNoise` as the `package` argument.

### Another example (Mapbox Navigation):

I had a similar issue when using the **MapBox Navigation** library. Instead of using adding it like I add other libraries, the documentation stated to use a [specific usage](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-ios/blob/f96b3d68ca8f59c2d177ab9c23a1a9825ecb1f4e/README.md):

> To install the MapboxNavigation framework in another package rather than an application, run `swift package init` to create a Package.swift, then add the following dependency:

```swift
// Latest prerelease
.package(name: "MapboxNavigation", url: "https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-ios.git", .exact("2.0.0-beta.11"))
```

Anyway, it looks like your [repo](https://github.com/GroupeMINASTE/SwiftMC/blob/master/Package.swift) is not using lineNoise anymore .

### Note to package developers:

Make sure your GitHub repo is the same name as your package name, it will just be more convenient.

Comment: And if you used dependency as local package like this to fix that:  .package(name: "name_your_local_package", path: "../another_folder_name") – this fix anyway not working => rename your folder or package. i hope it helps

Comment: .package(name:) is now deprecated, you can specify the name and package pair in your dependencies via .product. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71484022/spm-dependencies-branch-is-deprecated-on-xcode-13-3-and-swift-5-6