# SPM dependencies branch is deprecated on Xcode 13.3 and Swift 5.6

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-package-manager, xcode13

**Xcode 13.3** shows warnings for deprecation on the dependencies for external packages.

### For example:

```swift
// swift-tools-version:5.6
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "MyPackage",
    platforms: [
        .iOS(.v15)
    ],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "MyPackage",
            targets: ["MyTarget"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(
            name: "MyDependency", 
            url: "https://github.com/someorg/somepackage.git",
            .branch("main"))
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "MyTarget",
            dependencies: ["MyDependency"])
    ]
)
```

This shows the warning:

> 'package(name:url:_:)' is deprecated: use specific requirement APIs
> instead (e.g. use 'branch:' instead of '.branch')

However applying the recommended update makes the dependency not reachable anymore from `MyPackage`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is necessary to set the dependency as a **product**.

Specifically with `.product(name: [PackageName], package: [Name of repository])`, example:

```swift
// swift-tools-version:5.6
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "MyPackage",
    platforms: [
        .iOS(.v15)
    ],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "MyPackage",
            targets: ["MyTarget"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(
            url: "https://github.com/someorg/somepackage.git",
            branch: "main")
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "MyTarget",
            dependencies: [
                .product(
                    name: "MyDependency", 
                    package: "somepackage")])
    ]
)
```

### Update

This is still relevant in `Xcode 14.3.1` if you have a package with multiple products/libraries.